# (R) Changing size of xlab, ylab, and title in beanplot function from package beanplot

Tags: r, beanplot

I want to ask how to change the size of xlab, ylab, and title in beanplot function from beanplot package as I cannot find certain paremters for that.

Thanks in advance

I could not find any parameters to change size of texts in beanplot

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add a [MRE]. Maybe check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

The `beanplot` function uses the **base** graphics system. This means you can modify all graphics parameters using the `par` function.

```
# Save graphics parameters, setup 1x2 figure for the next plot
opar <- par(mfrow = c(1,2), cex.lab=1, cex.main=1)

beanplot(rnorm(22), rnorm(22), rnorm(22), main="Test!", rnorm(3), xlab="X-label")

# Change the size of the title and x-axis label
par(cex.lab=2, cex.main=3)
beanplot(rnorm(22), rnorm(22), rnorm(22), main="Test!", rnorm(3), xlab="X-label (x2)")

# Return to the previous state
par(opar)
```